# How do I add some HTML before & after the content for all posts?

Tags: html

I would like to add following html before & after a post content:

```
<ol style = "padding:0;margin:0"> 
    // post content
</ol>
```

How can I do this for all existing posts automatically?

Answer (score 6):

Make use of the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter. This way you can adjust/add/remove certain stuff from the content

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function ( $content )
{
    // Make sure we only target the main query's content, adjust as needed
    if ( !in_the_loop() )
        return $content;

    // We are targeting the correct content, so lets add what we need to
    $new_content  = '<ol style = "padding:0;margin:0">';
    $new_content .= $content;
    $new_content .= '</ol>';

    return $content = $new_content;
});
```

Comment: This code brought down my whole website after I added it into function.php.

Comment: You should do basic debugging and provide details. Simply saying it brought your website down is ineffecient. Please be specific with debug info. Anyways, there was a slight syntax error, which I have fixed now